# Replicating Variables In Blueprints Networking

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, amd-gpu

I am following this tutorial: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/HowTo/Networking/ReplicateVariable/Blueprints/index.html. On part 19. I am unable to find Blueprint `Effect_Fire`. My machine is running a AMD RYZEN 5 processor and AMD RADEON GRAPHICS card. This is Unreal Engine 4.2.1.

I have tried searching for the Blueprint `Effect_Fire` particle in my content browser, I cannot find it. The particle should be under `Content->StarterContent->Blueprints`.

Answer (score 0):

This linked post was on Unreal 4.9, wasn't it?

Trying update your UE4 to the same version as this tutorial, maybe you'll find it,
  if not, well... there still have some other way can get a similar result.

Comment: Good morning Kwang, Could you please review this link: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/Networking/Blueprints/index.html and tell me how to find the server logic and client logic nodes? I am trying to get the example under Authority working. I appreciate it, thanks. Abdullah

Comment: I made multiple players game before, `Switch has Authority` means check if you are server or not.  (Not actually, but you can think so.)
In multi-players game, there should be some events only Server can call it
(like reset the score for example).

Comment: You can do a simple test to check that, If you are following a tutorial to make a network game, then that should be two windows in your screen while playing, 
one is Server, the other is Client, let `Tick` node connect to your`Switch has Authority`,let it run every frame, and print some thing.

Comment: One of them will run to Authority which means it's Server, the other will run into Remote branch, because it's Client.

Comment: or You just want to know where is the location of `Server logic` or `Client logic` been defined?   Just right-click, and click `Find Reference`.

Comment: Good afternoon Kwang, I am following this link to add a HTTP request for networking functionality: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/UE4.10_How_To_Make_HTTP_GET_Request_in_C%2B%2B. An error occurred while trying to generate project files:

Comment: Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.22/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -

Comment: project="C:/Users/15039/Documents/Unreal Projects/CapstoneProject/CapstoneProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
While compiling C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE4Rules.dll:

Comment: c:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Plugins\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin-master\Source\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin.Build.cs(6,12) : error CS1729: 'UnrealBuildTool.ModuleRules' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
c:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Plugins\MySQLConnectorUE4Pl

Comment: ugin-master\Source\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin.Build.cs(11,9) : error CS0103: The name 'UEBuildConfiguration' does not exist in the current context

Comment: c:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Plugins\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin-master\Source\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin\MySQLCon

Comment: nectorUE4Plugin.Build.cs(14,3) : error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FileReference' could not be found

Comment: (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Plugins\MySQLConnectorUE4Pl

Comment: ugin-master\Source\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin.Build.cs(15,3) : error CS0103: The

Comment: name 'UProjectInfo' does not exist in the current context
c:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Plugins\MySQLConnectorUE4Pl

Comment: ugin-master\Source\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin\MySQLConnectorUE4Plugin.Build.cs(18,3) : error CS0246: The type

Comment: you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
ERROR: Unable to compile source files.

Comment: Could you please direct on how to fix this error? I don't want it to lead to the Unreal Engine project breaking. I appreciate your help, thank you. Best, Abdullah

Comment: LogPakFile: Registered encryption key '00000000000000000000000000000000': 0 pak files mounted, 0 remain pending
LogPlatformFile: Not using cached read wrapper

Comment: LogTaskGraph: Started task graph with 5 named threads and 23 total threads with 3 sets of task threads.

Comment: WOW oh,plz don't paste your error log in commit again, because that's really hard to read that, also, if you do not understand Unreal enough, I believe that most people will suggest you to avoid from changing or adding code in unreal.

Comment: Now, plz explain what you want to do with HTTP request?

Comment: Good Morning Kwang, Sorry about that error pasting, I apologize. I would like to please know how to add a networking component to an Unreal Engine game. I appreciate your effort. Thank you, Abdullah

Comment: https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/tech-blog/getting-started-with-unreal-multiplayer-in-cpp I am getting the error the The system cannot find the path specified when trying to launch the server. Could you please help? I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Well, that will be different problem from now on, I'll still help you.
Did you get this error when you enter command in cmd? or when you trying to play in editor?    I ask this question because enter command is not necessary, you'll contact cmd only after you finish packaging your game.